# correlation between attributes in fuzzy dataset

Tags: correlation, cart, fuzzy

I am new in this field. I want to ask if it is any simple way how to measure correlation between two attributes in data set. Data are defined by fuzzy logic. I have own implementation of fuzzy decision trees (FDT ordered, FDT ID3). I am able to predict new values from this model. I want to ask, if it is possible to get a correlation of attributes from this trees.

[what I have for now is showed in this article.](https://fedcsis.org/proceedings/2012/pliks/284.pdf)
 It is only for illustration. 
example of Data set (page 215) and example of tree (page 216)

Comment: By "correlation" do you mean the common statistical measure that is often derived from covariance? If so, I can offer several alternative formulas for calculating it in a fuzzy fashion. The catch with fuzzy set and logic metrics is keeping track of the many different variants and applying the right one for the problem at hand.

Comment: The fuzzy correlation formulas I'd give wouldn't be specific to that particular form of Decision Trees; you'd have to select which one best met your needs. From skimming the article it seems that you'd need one suited to triangular membership functions, which is doable.